# How large can a VMware datastore be? Name of VMWare software that monitors single server/multiple servers?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, distributed-computing, scalability

I had an interview and was asked the following questions about VMWare. I'm eager to know the answers, please help me :

1. How large can a VMware datastore be?
2. What is the name of the VMware software which runs locally on a PC that can monitor a single server based VMware host?
3. What is the name of the VMware software which runs on a server that can monitor multiple server based VMware hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The maximum supported VMDK size on an VMFS-5 datastore is increased to 62 TB. However, the maximum supported VMDK size on VMFS-3 is still 2 TB. The maximum supported size of a VMDK on NFS is the lesser of 62 TB and 1% less than the maximum file size supported by the NFS filesystem. (straight from the first google search for that particular question.)
2. vSphere Client
3. VCenter

I love VMware and I am still a noob.